# Whilst using Perl::FTP, What shall I put in the host field for connecting to a Local computer connected on the network

Tags: perl, ftp

I am using the Net::FTP in perl to do some file transfers. when I run the following code :-

Are there any issues with using the IP address ? Am I correct in providing this in the host field ?

```
use strict;          
use Net::FTP;

my $host = "10.77.69.124";
my $user = "administrator";
my $password = "Password";

my $f = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug =>0) or die "Can't open $host\n";
$f->login($user, $password) or die "Can't log  $user in\n";
```

The code is not able to connect to the remote host. Why is this happening ? Shouldn't this work with the IP address provided in the `$host` ?

Comment: You can try by putting `Debug => 1` to have more info about why it failed

Comment: Can you connect from that host with a "normal" ftp client using that IP address?

Comment: @mat can you suggest any normal client with which i can do some testing ?

Comment: @ccheneson and how will I print the debug information ? using `print Debug` ?

Comment: @return0: just use plain `ftp` on the command line.

Comment: It will print out to the standard output (if you run in the command line, it will be in the console)

Comment: telnet $host 21 is the simplest test.

Comment: @user1126070 I am not on a *nix machine man

Comment: Are you sure the target machine is actually running an FTP server? Trying to connect manually is the first thing to do.

Comment: @BillRuppert How do I make sure its running a FTP server or not? Actually I know I am going to come off as a retard here; but i do not have a lot of idea what an FTP server really is. is it like a web server which I have to install ? I assumed that since FTP is like an protocol, I will be able to send my file across to the network using this protocol and the perl commands that seem to *handle* this protocol. Where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The constructor of Net::FTP allows you to pass a single scalar value or an array of hosts to try. The value of this field should be the same as the PeerAddr from [IO::Socket::INET](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/IO-1.25/lib/IO/Socket/INET.pm#CONSTRUCTOR) (either a **hostname** or an ip **address**).

Have a closer look at what is happening by specifying Debug. If you are behind a firewall or a NAT setup, you should probably also set *Passive* to a non-zero value and make sure to check if the constructor failed by printing out $@.

```
my $ftp = Net::FTP->new(Host=>$host, Debug=>1, Passive=>1) || die $@;
```

If the constructor succeeded, you might want to check if any of the other methods fail:

```
$ftp->login($user, $pass) || die $ftp->message;
$ftp->cwd($path) || die $ftp->message;
```

By the way: If you are unsure if you've used the correct host parameter, you can ask Net::FTP which host it tried to connect to:

```
print $ftp->host, "\n";
```

If this still doesn't work, please provide a detailed output of your application.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

First be sure that you can reach the remote side:

From command line use telnet (available on linux and windows too, a it different in syntax)

```
telnet host 21
```

If you are not able to connect the from commandline, check for firewall rules or maybe your FTP server running on different port?

If you are able to connect try out login with plain FTP commands:

```
USER user@remote.host
PASS yourpassword
```

This will use ACTIVE ftp connection to the remote. This is the old way.

Nowadays most ftp server use PASSIVE ftp. To test try this command out (from linux commandline)

```
ftp -v -p host
```

In perl you could use passive mode this way:

```
my $f = Net::FTP->new($host, Debug =>1, Passive => 1) or die "Can't open $host\n";
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: what to put is $host ? the IP address ?

Comment: Either the IP or a name/address that resolves to the IP address. If you can ping it and get a IP it should work

Comment: @ØyvindSkaar it isnt. I tried with plain ping .. where it connects .. but then through the perl code, the ftp connection is getting timed out.

Comment: @return0 But that doesn't mean the $host is wrong.. Are you sure you can actually connect to the ftp server? I'm sure there's a more "windows like" way of debugging this, but what user1126070 suggested should work as well.